# Questions which were migrated away appear in the Related list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migrated-questions, related-questions

I am seeing questions which were migrated away to another site appearing in the related questions list in the right sidebar when viewing a question.

I viewed the question [Interesting addressing scheme](https://serverfault.com/q/520952/126632) and in the Related list on the right, one of the questions shown was [What is an ITP address?](https://serverfault.com/q/519745/126632?noredirect=1), which was migrated to SU.

Shouldn't questions which were migrated to another site *not appear* in this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrated questions are auto-deleted after a month. They'll disappear from the list after that.

So it's a self-correcting problem - unless you want it gone immediately.