# Questions migrated away still appear on front page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, migration

[This question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/buying-a-software-tool-should-i-buy-myself-or-should-the-client-do-so) was migrated from [Worldbuilding.SE] to [Freelancing.SE].

Then why do we still see it on the front page of Worldbuilding? -->

[image]

Shouldn't it be kept out of that selection?

If so, consider this a feature request.

[Edited to add:]
Oh. We could just do nothing: [Questions which were migrated away appear in the Related list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187456/189029). But the front page is more important than the related list IMO.

Comment: It's not deleted, just migrated, so it's acting same way as question being closed. Can't see any reason why not to show it, unless you also ask to not show closed questions?

Answer (score 2):

Migration is actually closure of a question, as off topic, on the original site where it was posted.

Since closed questions appear on the front page (unless having negative score lower than the per-site threshold) I can't see any valid reason to treat migrated questions in a different way.

Being visible in the front page allow users chance to follow it and appeal the migration (flag, vote to close on the new site) same way they can appeal "ordinary" closure of a question.

Note that after 30 days migrated question is auto deleted from the source site, so it won't appear in its question lists anymore.